# Reorder an array with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array like that:

```
tableObj =  [
  {
    label: 'here',
    value: 36,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 0
  },
  {
    label: 'are',
    value: 42,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'some',
    value: 21,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 2
  },
  {
    label: 'tags',
    value: 26,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 3
  }
];
```

When I display the content of the array, I do that:

```
$(".sortable-list").sortable({
  axis: "y",
  containment: ".sortable-list",
  revert: true,
  start: function(event, ui) { 
    var updt = ui.item.index();
    tableObj.value = updt;
  },
  update: function(event, ui) { 
    var updt = ui.item.index();
    tableObj.index = updt;
  }
});
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

Where the display is `<li>` tags in between an empty `<ul class=".sortable-list"></ul>`.
What I want to do is dragging the `<li>` tags and reorder the elements, and by clicking a button, I want to capture the new state of the array.
Which means, if I move the second element in first position, when I click the button, the array is reordered with the second element in position 0.
All I manage to do with this jQuery functions above is to set a new value, but I can't manage to capture the new array reordered.

Anyone can help me please ? Thank You in advance ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Alexandr Fedotov! He drove me on the right path! :)
Here is my solution:

```
var manipulate, oldIndex;
$(".sortable-list").sortable({
     axis: "y",
     containment: ".sortable-list",
     revert: true,

     start: function(event, ui) { 
          var updt = ui.item.index();
          manip = updt;
          console.log("Start: " + manipulate);
          oldIndex = sortableList[manipulate];
     },

     update: function(event, ui) { 
          var newIndex = ui.item.index();
          console.log("End: " + newIndex);
          sortableList.splice(manipulate, 1);
          sortableList.splice(newIndex, 0, oldIndex);

          console.log(sortableList);
          }
   });

   $(".sortable-list").disableSelection();
```

I had to create a table every time I added a `<li>`. Then, I catch who's the one who is dragged and drop. In the function "update", we remove the item from the array (previously save into the variable `oldIndex`) then we add it into its new index in the array.
I hope this will help somebody else!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `var newList=$(".sortable-list").sortable("toArray")`

Check this Codepen examples:

https://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/qvbCr?editors=1111

https://codepen.io/fraigo/pen/WawQBy

Comment: Thanks, but I manipulate objects, displayed in <li> tags.Not only the <li> tags and there content. I want to capture the objects in the array, reordered, not the <li> tags reordered.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: modify your markup a bit, to add data-attribute to each li, which contains an identifier of the current element from tableObj array.

In the update function get the identifier of the currently moved element:

```
var id = $(event.toElement).data('id');
```

Using this identifier find the element in the tableObj array:

```
var obj = tableObj.find(function(o) { return o.id === id});
```

Afterwards find an old index of the recently moved object:

```
var oldIndex = tableObj.indexOf(obj);
```

Getting a new index of the object:

```
var newIndex = ui.item.index();
```

Then remove obj from old position and insert at the new index:

```
tableObj.slice(oldIndex, 1);
tableObj.slice(newIndex, 0, obj);
```

Afterwards you will have your array with correct order of element(same as on the view). If you don't need to reorder array on the fly - you can create a copy of the original array and perform modifications on the copy.